# Substring in nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a nvarchar column in table that stores data as '{CRLF}' separated values. Those values can be in the format 'namespace#name$value' but also in other formats.

I need to extract separated namespace, name and value and skip data in other formats. I can do it with a query:

```
select 
  SUBSTRING([value], 1, CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1) as paramNamespace,
  SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('#',[value]) + 1, CHARINDEX('$',[value]) - CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1) as paramName,
  SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('$',[value]) + 1, LEN([value])) as paramValue
FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE((select data from test where Id = 1), '{CRLF}', CHAR(7)), CHAR(7))
WHERE [value] LIKE '%#%$%'
```

However, when I try also to filter in by paramName with this query:

```
select * from (select 
  SUBSTRING([value], 1, CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1) as paramNamespace,
  SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('#',[value]) + 1, CHARINDEX('$',[value]) - CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1) as paramName,
  SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('$',[value]) + 1, LEN([value])) as paramValue
FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE((select data from test where Id = 1), '{CRLF}', CHAR(7)), CHAR(7))
WHERE [value] LIKE '%#%$%') a
where paramName IN ('name', 'name3')
```

it returns

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

It looks like "WHERE [value] LIKE '%#%$%'" weren't executed first and it tries to substring value in other format.

How should I write this query to filter it by paramName?

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (Id INT, data nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, N'namespace#name$value{CRLF}somedatainotherformat{CRLF}namespace2#name2$value2{CRLF}namespace3#name3$value3{CRLF}');
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5d71/1

Comment: *"I have a nvarchar column in table that stores data as '{CRLF}' separated values"* This is the *real* problem though. Fix your design and you don't have this issue. Never store delimited data in your database.

Comment: That is what I use this query for, it is part of stored procedure which extract values from delimated data and stores it in correct columns.

Comment: So, from your sample data, what are your expected results here?

Comment: In my simple data there are 3 values in correct format, so they are splitted into 3 rows with paramNames 'name', 'name2' and 'name3'. I want to filter it so it returns only 2 rows with 'name' and 'name3', but when I added 'where paramName IN ('name', 'name3')' it returns error.

Comment: case when charindex('#',value) <1 then '' 
               else SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('#',[value]) + 1, CHARINDEX('$',[value]) - CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1) 
               END 
               as paramName,
 That some otherdata is messing with the parsing and the name,name3 cannot be evaluated prior to that

Comment: Specifically those derived 3 columns are 3 compute scalers and the filter will be applied after the first compute scalar on param name hence the reason you don't need the case for the other columns. So it's split into rows --> eval param name as a compute scaler as it's in WHERE to filter to reduce later computations --> apply other compute scalers --> return results

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `PARSENAME` to split the data into columns is what you are after:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (Id int,
                   data nvarchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1, N'namespace#name$value{CRLF}somedatainotherformat{CRLF}namespace2#name2$value2{CRLF}namespace3#name3$value3{CRLF}');
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test t
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(t.data,'{CRLF}','|'),'|') SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(TRANSLATE(SS.[value],'$#','..'),3),PARSENAME(TRANSLATE(SS.[value],'$#','..'),2),PARSENAME(TRANSLATE(SS.[value],'$#','..'),1)))V(paramNamespace, paramName, paramValue)
WHERE V.paramName IN ('name', 'name3')
GO

DROP TABLE test;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot guarantee that there won't be any dots in the data, especially in namespaces. Also, there may be some dot separated data that would produce a false positive result. That is why I can not use PARSENAME, but I combined your approach with the substraings from my query and it returned the expected results.

Comment: Then replace the dots with something else and replace them back afterwards, @grzegorzorwat . I can only base the solution on the samples you give.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
Select paramNamespace = substring(v.data, 1, p1.pos - 2)
     , paramName = substring(v.data, p1.pos, p2.pos - p1.pos - 1)
     , paramValue = substring(v.data, p2.pos, p3.pos - p2.pos - 1)
 From test As t
Cross Apply string_split(replace(t.data, '{CRLF}', '|'), '|') As s
Cross Apply (Values (concat(s.value, '#$'))) As v(data)
Cross Apply (Values (charindex('#', v.data, 1) + 1)) As p1(pos)
Cross Apply (Values (charindex('$', v.data, p1.pos) + 1)) As p2(pos)
Cross Apply (Values (charindex('#', v.data, p2.pos) + 1)) As p3(pos)  --end of set
Where p2.pos - p1.pos > 1;
```

We concat the delimiters to the end - and then filter out any rows where the difference between the delimiters is greater than 1.  So any rows that have only '#$' or rows that start with '#$' or rows that have some other value that does not include either of the delimiters.

If you have data that can have either delimiter - but not the other, you need to filter those out some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I combined Larnu's query with my and created a query that separates only the data in the expected format and then filters it:

```
SELECT paramName, paramValue
FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE((select data from test where Id = 1),'{CRLF}',CHAR(7)),CHAR(7)) SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING([value], 1, CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1),
        SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('#',[value]) + 1, CHARINDEX('$',[value]) - CHARINDEX('#',[value]) - 1),
        SUBSTRING([value], CHARINDEX('$',[value]) + 1, LEN([value]))))V(paramNamespace, paramName, paramValue)
WHERE ss.value LIKE '%#%$%' and paramName IN ('name', 'name3')
```

But I still don't understand why the subquery from my question produces an error.